# Batch file to check windows activation status

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to be able to script my windows activation checks. My code is below, the first line is the bit I would appreciate some assistance with, the rest is there mainly to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
if slmgr /dli = True (
    do something
    ) else (
        do something else
        )
    )
```

The first line will never work the way I have it I understand that not sure how to go about checking the activation status, again all help and advice appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in (
    'cscript //nologo "%systemroot%\system32\slmgr.vbs" /dli ^| find "License Status:"' 
) do set "licenseStatus=%%a"

if /i "%licenseStatus%"=="Licensed" (
  do something
) else (
  do something
)
```

BUT the output from slmgr is completly localized. It will only work in english locale.

Comment: @NorbertBoros, `slmgr.vbs` tries to load locale information from an `.ini` file (see the `LoadResourceData` function)  . The path to this file is determined by the UI locale information, full script path and script file name. If the file is not found, english locale will be used. You can simply copy the script to another place (`%temp%`?) and run this script copy instead of the original one.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason MC ND script exited before it run the if /i line

so I did this instead:

```
cscript //nologo "%systemroot%\system32\slmgr.vbs" /dli 2>nul | find "License Status:" | find "Licensed" >nul

IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    EXIT /b 0
) ELSE (
    EXIT /b 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the following code:
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in (
'cscript //nologo "%systemroot%\system32\slmgr.vbs" /dli ^| find "License Status:"'
) do set "licenseStatus=%%a"

if /i "%licenseStatus%"=="Licensed" (
do something
) else (
do something

Alternatively, you can visit the link [KMSpico](https://freekmspico.com/) for more information.